# G++, SDL Compilation problem (compiler does not see the library)

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, sdl-2

after updating g++ to 11.2.0 (before that I had a very old version), I can't compile my project with the same command. For some reason, the compiler cannot find the sdl library, although everything worked fine before.

```
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\****>g++ -I/src/include -L/src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried to use the local path, but still unsuccessful. Then it gives me this error.

```
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****>g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2_image.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2_image.a when searching for -lSDL2_image
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You know `-I/src/include` is an absolute path, right? Maybe you meant `-Isrc/include`?

Comment: I expect the new error is related to mixing 32 and 64 bit

Comment: Maybe you want to switch to use msys2 to provide your mingw and have its package manager install the proper SDL binaries for you. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)